# How to post in a blog without command prompt when using octopress in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, octopress

I am using octopress gem for implementing blog using ruby on rails. I got some code from
http://www.nickhammond.com/setting-octopress-jekyll-blog-rails-application/
and its work fine.

But my question is for creating a new post every time I have to write code in command prompt like

```
    rake new_post['Hello World']
    rake generate
```

I want something like admin panel where should be textbox, textare and submit button. and when I click on submit button it should be posted. Is it possible to create here using octopress? Please share with me, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at a tool like [this](https://github.com/yortz/octopress-admin).

I haven't used it personally, but that's what I get from a simple Google search.

Personally, I'm using GitHub Pages for my Octopress stuff - I was looking for the same sorta thing you're looking for, and came across [this](http://darvin.github.io/2013/01/13/Prose_Octopress_TravisIO/). Obviously this is only handy if you're using GitHub for source, but you could edit your source using Prose, acting as a nice Markdown-friendly interface, and then use something like Travis-CI to compile and deploy.

I haven't set this up yet myself though, so I can't speak from experience. But I plan to. :D